# React How to get the current ref data by assigning values in the loop？

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hooks for beginners. Thank you
How can I write to get the offsettop of each click

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
const node = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
{Array.from({ length: 10 }).map((item, i) => (
   <div
      className='sw-tab'
      ref={node}
      key={i}
      onClick={(event) => {
        // Every click is the value of the last item, not the value of the current click
        console.log(node.current?.offsetTop);
      }}
    >
      <span>1111{i}</span>
    </div>
))}
```

Thank you thank you!!!

Comment: The current development environment is typescript react

Answer (score 1):

you can access the offset like this

```
console.log(event.target.offsetTop);
```

Comment: I tried
But the vscode hint
Property 'offsettop' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

thank

Answer (score 0):

```
const ele = event.target as HTMLElement;
console.log(ele.offsetTop);
```

Using type assertion solves the problem.
Thank you very much